# Couldnt get CSRF to work with ajax (CI 2.1)

Tags: codeigniter-2

i am trying to get CSRF work with ajax in my CI 2.1 application.

i have searched about this and found few guidlines, but couln't resolve the problem
http://ericlbarnes.com/post/10728867961/codeigniter-csrf-protection-with-ajax
http://www.beheist.com/index.php/en/blog/csrf-protection-in-codeigniter-2-0-a-closer-look
http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20

i have set two different tokens for two token values in the config

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'token01';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'token02';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

Here is my view, i am using form_open

```
<?php echo form_open("http://localhost/pis/user"); ?>
<div id="inputs">

<?php echo form_input($username);?>
<?php echo form_password($password);?>
</div>


<div id="actions">

<div style="float:left"><?php echo form_submit($submit);?>

<!-- <input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="clicksubmit()" /> -->

</div>

</div>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

I am using this javascript to make async call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


      $("#submit").click( 

        function(){
            var form_data = {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
                csrf_token_name: $("input[name=token01]").val()
            };


            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/pis/user",
            data: form_data,
            success: 
              function(data){
                $("#debug").html(data.message).css({'background-color' : data.bg_color}).fadeIn('slow'); 
              }

            });

          return false;

        });


    });

</script>
```

When i run this i am getting a "500 Internal Server Error" along with the "An Error Was Encountered, The action you have requested is not allowed" as a response. Firebug shows the POST data parameters correctly.

eg: username=root&password=root&csrf_token_name=31961f17de5fa2df657ab1aba880f718

**How ever if i removed the csrf, ajax request runs fine and i get 200 as response**

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. I should use token name instead of csrf_token_name in js file.

token01: $("input[name=token01]").val()

Comment: Please add this as the answer to the question and accept it in order to remove this question from the unanswered stack.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you can just let jQuery serialize the form data for you:

```
var form_data = $(this).serialize();
```

This way you won't have to worry about inputs being renamed or more fields being added.